# ASP.Net MVC Get Area Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Given a Controller name, and a Action name - "AdminController", "Index" for example, is it possible for me to get back all the possible Areas.

Does that make any sense to anyone?

Cheer,

ETFairfax.

Comment: Like this? http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: You have the controller name and the action name, and you want a list of all the areas that have that controller name and action name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really supported to do this.  In MVC 2, controllers aren't associated with areas.  The way the implementation works is that the route is associated with a set of namespaces, and the controller factory looks only in those namespaces for a controller type to service the request.  So there's no direct mapping from a controller to an area.

If you explain a little bit more on what you're trying to do, perhaps we can find an alternative method for getting you unstuck.